# Salty Chili and too spicy

Tags: tomatoes, chili-peppers, chili

I cooked chili with lime/chili pepper seasonings. It's too salty and too spicy. How do I fix it?

The seasonings were packaged by Whole Foods, called Tequila Lime Seasonings

Comment: What are the seasonings? Were they seasoning blends? If so, they may have contained additional salt. If you can, please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you make a sauce less spicy/hot?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/how-can-you-make-a-sauce-less-spicy-hot)

Answer (score 1):

It's actually fairly difficult to fix directly; your best option is to try to add something sweet; you can try just tomatoes, but could also cook together some carrots (finely chopped), bell pepper and onions  until well softened and the onions have browned some and then mix that into the chili.  You may need quite a lot depending on how far past palletable the chili is.  It may be easier to add sugar directly, but too much and it won't seem like chili anymore.

Serving it with something with fat in it will help to cut the spiciness of the chili (avocado, sour cream, cheese), and may help with the saltiness (if it isn't a really salty cheese).

For the saltiness problem, I'd be inclined to serve the chili over something else that's fairly bland, such as a baked potato, which will help with both problems.  You could also go with cincinatti style, and serve it over pasta (possibly with beans, but if they're canned beans, make sure to rinse them well so you're not adding back in too much sauce).

Comment: Thank you, Joe. The seasonings were packaged by Whole Foods, called Tequila Lime Seasonings. I fixed it by adding ketchup, light brown sugar and Worcestershire Sauce.