# Medium sauces versus Mild!

Tags: spicy-hot

I can never remember which is hot. NOw i have a medium enchilada sauce in my recipe and need to cool the heat way down... help! How do I make my meal so that my child will be able to eat it. She does not like spicy.

Comment: see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1120/67

Comment: Hello Kandice and welcome to the site! Your question already has an answer here: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/how-can-you-make-a-sauce-less-spicy-hot. Most likely your question will be closed as a duplicate. This has nothing to do with you, it happens to all of us. It's somewhat unclear to me, what you mean by "remembering which is hot". "Hot" with regard to spices refers to the burning sensation some spices leave in your mouth, so the range of spicyness/burning increases from  mild->medium->hot.

Answer (score 4):

Mild is the opposite of hot. Medium is in-between. If the sauce ends up too hot for your child, try a dollop of sour cream or plain yogurt.